# How to put view in specific location in ZStack based on another view?

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui

I have a view in a ScrollView and base on an offset value. There is another view that needs to animate out.

This view is under the gray box but it places its base on a hardcoded value. How to pin the green box under the gray area without a hardcoded value? Using the hard coded value will not be consistent with other devices.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var contentOffset = CGFloat(0)
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    TrackableScrollView { offset in
                        contentOffset = offset.y
                    } content: {
                        VStack(spacing: 0) {
                            Text("Hello World")
                                .padding()
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .background(Color.gray)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Text("HELLO")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .opacity(contentOffset < -16 ? 0 : 1)
                    .animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.2), value: contentOffset)
                    .offset(y: -280)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            .background(AccountBackground())
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

What it looks like:

[image]

When you scroll up the green box will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to an overlay to your ZStack. If you have a navigation bar the offset that you need to give it is 0 as it will be placed automatically below it. The TrackableScrollView is a preference key that is commonly found online to track the scrolling position of the scroll view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var contentOffset = CGFloat(0)
    @State private var offsetPositionValue: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var heightOfFrame: CGFloat = 0
    
    @State private var isShyHeaderVisible = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                TrackableScrollView { offset in
                    withAnimation {
                        contentOffset = offset.y
                    }
                } content: {
                    Text("Hello World")
                }
                .overlay(
                    ZStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Total number of points")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .lineLimit(1)
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Text("20,000 pts")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding(.leading, 50)
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .padding(.vertical, 8)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                        .background(Color.green)
                        .offset(y: contentOffset < -16 ? 0 : heightOfFrame - 5)
                        .opacity(contentOffset < -16 ? 1 : 0)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .top))
                    }
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                )
            }
            .navigationTitle("Hello")
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            .background(AccountBackground())
        }
    }
}
```